# SuperCSV - Parsing multiple columns to a List

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

Given the following example csv data

`name,address,sibling,sibling,sibling
John,MainSt,Sarah,Mike,Greg`

and the example POJO that I want to parse the data into

```
public class Employee {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private List<String> siblings;

   public Employee() { }  

   public void setName(String name) { ... }
   public void setAddress(String address { ... }
   public void setSiblings(List<String> siblings) { ... }
}
```

and the following field mapping

```
String[] fieldMapping = new String[]{
    "name",
    "address",
    "siblings[0]",
    "siblings[1]",
    "siblings[2]"
}
```

and the following cell processors

```
CellProcessors[] processors = new CellProcessors[]{
    new NotNull(),    // name
    new NotNull(),    // address
    new NotNull(),    // siblings[0]
    new NotNull(),    // siblings[1]
    new NotNull()     // siblings[2]
}
```

I would expect to be able to parse the csv data into `Employee` without a problem, however I am receiving the following exception

`org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvReflectionException: unable to find method setSiblings[0](java.lang.String) in class com.Employee - check that the corresponding nameMapping element matches the field name in the bean, and the cell processor returns a type compatible with the field`

This is how I do the actual parsing

```
List<Employee> deserializedRecords = new ArrayList<>();
try (ICsvBeanReader beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(file), CsvPreferences.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)) {
    beanReader.getHeader(true);
    Employee model;
    while ((model = (Employee) beanReader.read(Employee.class, fieldMapping, processors)) != null) {
        deserializedRecords.add(model);
    }
}
```

This pretty much follows the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145412/how-to-write-liststring-to-csv-file-read-it-back-using-supercsv/21161854#21161854), and after reading the SuperCSV documentation, I'm not entirely sure why the exception is getting thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `CsvBeanReader` which doesn't support indexed (or deep) mapping. You're looking for `CsvDozerBeanReader` (examples [here](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_dozer.html)).